# Get RecyclerView to itext pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-recyclerview, itext

I want to get recyclerView Items from activity to itext PDF, but I don't know the best way to do it.

I tried to do that by taking abitmap for recyclerView and put it in the PDF,but it was of lower quality than the other text in PDF

```java
Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rl_edu.getWidth(), rl_edu.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(returnedBitmap, 595, 842, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);

Drawable bgDrawable = rl_edu.getBackground();
if (bgDrawable != null) {
    bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
} else {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
}
l_edu.draw(canvas);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
returnedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
image.setAlignment(Element.LISTITEM);
image.scaleAbsolute(490f, 240f);
mDoc.add(image);
```

And I also tried to get toString from Infrormation Activity for the recyclerView

```java
Font f = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 14.0f, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLUE);
String rvEdu = MyApplication.getEducationList().toString();
mDoc.add(new Paragraph(rvEdu, f));
```

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: what kind of data you are writing to pdf?

Comment: texts and pictures @GhazanfarAteeb

Comment: Draw the view to the built in pdfdocument https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument . The question is how many items in the recyclerview? and do you want to match standard paper sizes? (As you might need to break it up in to multiple pages.

Comment: as far i remember I've worked with writing images to pdf. i could share that

Comment: I've done this previously. But I encountered many problems that I could not solve, so I try to do that using iText.
The number of items in RecyclerView is not specified, depending on the user's input @Andrew

Comment: I draw views to pdfdocument lots, the only problem I had was with pre Android 6 in that if you put a bitmap in then it did not compress it and produced very large pdf files. Otherwise it produces just as good results as itext without having to pay for a license (unless your app is open source). So what problems did you have?

Comment: I could not determine the number of pages on which the information is placed because it is a variable value according to the user's input
I was converting the final form into a bitmap and then putting the batmap into a PDF file, but the final result is a very long page or a page that does not show all the information
I tried to split the bitmap before placing it in the PDF page, but I did not get any result  @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to create a multi page pdf from a recyclerview, it does not use itext because there is no need to as the underlying graphics system Android uses is [Skia](https://skia.org/) which has renderers for hardware, bitmap and pdf's

Thus it does not have the license issue non open source use.

This example is based on something I do in my app for non recyclerviews.

The key is to pre-measure all the recycler items (not just the ones that the recycler needs to show on the screen) and thus you can build a view to draw to the pdf that fits the pdf page.

Note that you need to treat a pdf page as a large low resolution screen, much as your app has adapt to display on different screen sizes.

This is because an A4 pdf page is only 594 postscript (pixels) wide and 841 postscript (pixels) high. Thus you probably want to use much smaller font sizes than you would for a devices screen (This basic example does not adjust for the pdf size)

As it is a complete working example I put it on github https://github.com/Zardozz/RecyclerviewPdf

Note you should really do the PDF generation in the background because it can take some time as it draws all items in the recyclerview.